# Page.Parsecontrol converts asp:textbox to textarea not input

Tags: asp.net

I'm injecting some generated asp.net controls into a page using Page.ParseControl. I'm injecting the markup as follows:

```
Me.phScript.Controls.Add(Me.Page.ParseControl("<asp:TextBox runat=""server"" id=""txtAreaOfConcern"" TextMode=""multiline"" Rows=""5"" Width=""300"" MaxLength=""5"" />", True))
```

Now when this is rendered the source html comes out as

```
<textarea name="txtAreaOfConcern" rows="5" cols="20" id="txtAreaOfConcern" style="width:300px;">
```

Wheras a textbox added as per normal renders as follows:

```
<input name="_tbStaticInput" type="text" maxlength="20" id="_tbStaticInput" style="height:104px;width:263px;" />
```

The reason this is such a problem is that i no longer have the maxlength attribute which is needed for this page.

Is it possible to render an input through control injection, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the TextMode to multiline in the string you are passing to ParseControl, you will always get a textarea, that's how the TextBox control works.  It will do the same thing if you put that in the markup on the page or instantiated a TextBox class and set the TextMode property to multiline.

Not related to your problem but it seems a strange way to create a control dynamically, the text you are parsing is a string literal and is not dynamic in any way.  Why don't you just instantiate a TextBox class and set the properties, that way you get compile time checking that you are setting the properties to valid values.  The way you are doing it your string could be changed to "AnIvalidValue" and everything would still compile fine but you would get a run time exception.

Comment: You are right, it is a strange way to add controls, something i'm stuck with i'm affraid. Its a 'page flow' system where you start off with 1500lines of XML, perform two XSL transforms on it to get your page and then render that. First pass selects the data, second turns it to aspx/html before handing off to asp.net. Very scary, don't worry - i'm getting out. 

So what you are saying is that with a multiline textbox, you can't limit the number of characters?

Comment: You could do it but it is much more complex than just setting the MaxLength property. On the client side you could do something using javascript where it counted the number of chars in the text area on each keypress and stopped more character being entered when it hit a specified limit.  You would also have to do some server side validation to check that the user hadn't bypassed the javascript somehow.  I would normaly use a CustomValidator for this, not sure how that fits into your framework.